# Как получить подстроку?

Tags: visual-basic

Есть переменная `StringA$`:

> `StringA$ = "ABCDEFG"`

Нужно создать вторую переменную `StringB$`, значение которой должно быть равно 4-му и 5-му символу переменной `StringA$`:

> `StringB$ = "DE"` // 4-ый и 5-ый символ из переменной `StringA$`

Как это сделать?

Comment: Пользуюсь программой PureBasic 5.11

Comment: Вот я например знаю как это сделать в PHP: $stringA = 'ABCDEFG'; $stringB = $stringA[3].$stringA[4]; // 3 и 4, потому что счёт начинается с нуля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
StringB$ = Mid$(StringA$, 4, 2)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только после команды "Mid" - $ не нужна. Итог: ... Mid(...).

Comment: @Lesperanza, на VB6 оба варианта работоспособны, но вариант с `$` лучше, потому что при нём не происходит конвертирования из Variant в String. Про PureBasic не в курсе.

Comment: В PureBasic нет типа `Variant`, а `Mid` возвращает тип `String`.

Comment: @user183838, спасибо за информацию.